# Wordpress > Redirect 301 from domain A to domain B with the same slug

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

We have a Wordpress website and we've imported a thousands of posts from an old website (Domain A) to a new website (Domain B)

During the import, we made sure that the posts Slugs remain unchanged.

So now we want to create redirects on domain B .htaccess file to be able to do that :

redirect all the URLS [http://www.domainA.com/listings/[Slug]](http://www.domainA.com/listings/%5BSlug%5D) to [http://www.domainB.com/fr/listings/[Slug]](http://www.domainB.com/fr/listings/%5BSlug%5D)   (Knowing that [slug] remain the same)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please share your .htaccess file in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}/ listing
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.old-domain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.new-domain.com/listing/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Hi Dinesh 
Thank you for your answer
I added the code to the old domain .htaccess. 

Now here is what's happening with this code added : 

http://www.old-domain.com (homepage) is now redirecting to http://www.new-domain.com/listing /// which is not correct. 

I want to redirect only pages with http://www.old-domain.com/listing/any-url-slug to http://www.new-domain.com/fr/listing/the-same-url-slug 

All the other pages from the Old domain will redirect to another specific pages on the new domain (i can do that)